# My StringRequest is causing a volley error of null

Tags: php, android, networking, android-volley

I have spent hours debugging this problem and I felt like I was really close to getting it working but I just can't figure this error out. I know for a fact that my URL is correct and that my PHP code works. I verified this by putting the URL into the browser of the phone running the app and it returned to me the correct JSON object in the main HTML body of the resulting page. Additionally if I set up my PHP code to have an error (I made a var undefined) then the code will show that as a Login Response and the volley will not error.

So I know for a fact that the PHP code returns a valid response and that I am making a valid connection to my server, thus the error isn't there. Whenever the PHP is valid then there is a Volley error before it receives a response from the PHP. Something has to be wrong with the Volley, but I don't know what it is.

Other details that might help: 
   -For whatever reason it seems to be calling getParams() twice.

The code for the entire String Request, errors, and App Singleton are below.

### Here is the code for my String Request:

```
private void loginUser( final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "login";
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in...");
    showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                    // Launch User activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            LoginActivity.this,
                            UserActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", user);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley Error in login Activity: " + error.getMessage());
            for(int i = 0; i<error.getStackTrace().length; i++)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Class name for Stack Trace element " + i +": " + error.getStackTrace()[i].getClassName());
                Log.e(TAG, "File name for Stack Trace element " + i +": " + error.getStackTrace()[i].getFileName());
                Log.e(TAG, "Line Number for Stack Trace element " + i +": " + error.getStackTrace()[i].getLineNumber());
                Log.e(TAG, "Method name for Stack Trace element " + i +": " + error.getStackTrace()[i].getMethodName());
                Log.e(TAG, "Result from isNativeMethod " + i +": " + error.getStackTrace()[i].isNativeMethod());
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
}
```

And here is the error message I get: 
    E/LoginActivity: Volley Error in Login Activity: null

### Here is the data from the stack trace loop that I ran on the Volley error

```
Class name for Stack Trace element 0: com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork
             File name for Stack Trace element 0: BasicNetwork.java
             Line Number for Stack Trace element 0: 173
             Method name for Stack Trace element 0: performRequest
             Result from isNativeMethod 0: false
Class name for Stack Trace element 1: com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher
             File name for Stack Trace element 1: NetworkDispatcher.java
             Line Number for Stack Trace element 1: 131
             Method name for Stack Trace element 1: processRequest
             Result from isNativeMethod 1: false
Class name for Stack Trace element 2: com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher
             File name for Stack Trace element 2: NetworkDispatcher.java
             Line Number for Stack Trace element 2: 111
             Method name for Stack Trace element 2: processRequest
             Result from isNativeMethod 2: false
Class name for Stack Trace element 3: com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher
             File name for Stack Trace element 3: NetworkDispatcher.java
             Line Number for Stack Trace element 3: 90
             Method name for Stack Trace element 3: run
             Result from isNativeMethod 3: false
```

---

### Volley Singleton Code:

```
public class AppSingleton {
private static AppSingleton mAppSingletonInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mContext;

private AppSingleton(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized AppSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mAppSingletonInstance == null) {
        mAppSingletonInstance = new AppSingleton(context);
    }
    return mAppSingletonInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req,String tag) {
    req.setTag(tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
}
```

---

### Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycallstracker.mycallstracker">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".UserActivity" />
</application>
```